# Setter property in unmarshlling JAXB?

Tags: java, xml, web-services, jakarta-ee, jaxb

JAXB-> After unmarshalling the XML into Java object, is it possible to set the updated values in the object by using the setter property? Please show some example for setting the value and if we marshall the object back to XML the changes would be get reflected? Please advise

Answer (score 0):

JAXB performs XML to Java conversion (unmarshall) and also Java to XML conversion (marshall).

Try this [hello world tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/java/jaxb-hello-world-example/) to convert a Java object to XML

The example class (with @XmlRootElement)

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Customer {
    String name;
    int id;
```

Create the object and set the properties

```
Customer customer = new Customer();
customer.setId(100);
customer.setName("mkyong");
```

Marshal the Customer object to a file in XML format

```
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Customer.class);
Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
jaxbMarshaller.marshal(customer, file);
```